# Fluent NHibernate Mapping for a Category / Sub-Categories Tree

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, mapping, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following model class for my '**Category**' object:

```
public virtual int Id { get; set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }

public virtual IList<Category> SubCategories { get; set; }
```

This is my fluent nhibernate mapping class for '**Category**':

```
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();

Map(x => x.Name);
References(x => x.ParentCategory).Column("ParentCategoryId");

// ** THE BELOW MAPPING IS WHAT I'M UNSURE ABOUT **
HasMany(x => x.SubCategories).Where(x => x.Id == x.ParentCategory.Id);
```

My database that this relates to consists of a number of 'categories', some of which are at root level (and have a ParentCategoryId = NULL) and all others are sub-categories, which may be only 1 level deep, or may be 3,4,5 levels deep (recursive parents back up to a root/parent CategoryId.

Example of relationship between rows/records:

```
Cars (Id = 1 - ParentCategoryId = NULL)
Cars (Id = 1) > Hatchback (Id = 2 - ParentCategoryId = 1)
Cars (Id = 1) > Hatchback (Id = 2) > Ford (Id = 3 - ParentCategoryId = 2)

Motorcycles (Id = 4 - ParentCategoryId = NULL)
Motorcycles (Id = 4) > Scooters (Id = 5 - ParentCategoryId = 4)
```

The '**SubCategories**' property within my Category class needs to retrieve all Categories that have a '**ParentCategoryId**' of the current Category(Id), but I'm unsure how I go about mapping this. I've tried the HasMany mapping shown in the above example, but that failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I have just implemented a working solution to this by changing the HasMany mapping to the following:

```
HasMany(x => x.SubCategories)
.Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
.KeyColumn("ParentCategoryId")
.Where(x => x.ParentCategory.Id == x.Id)
```

Comment: when I implement the above, i get the correct relationship of categories and its subcategories. eg: 1 =>4,5 ; 2=>6,7. But i also get the list subcategories. so the final looks like 1=>4,5 ; 2=>6,7 ; 4 ; 5 ; 6 ; 7. The 4-7, which are actually subcategories, also are retrieved in the same level at categories. Hope I am making sense to you. How did u solve that?